# Grab one specific column from multiple csv files and merge into one

Tags: python, excel, loops, csv, pandas

I'd like to grab only the data in the 4th column from all my csv files and write the data into a single file. Each 4th column has a unique header name with the name of the root folder+csv name like `FolderA1`

FolderA /

```
1.csv |INFO  INFO  INFO  FolderA1  INFO
       Apple Apple Apple Orange    Apple

2.csv |INFO  INFO  INFO  FolderA2 INFO
       Apple Apple Apple Cracker  Apple

3.csv |INFO  INFO  INFO  FOLDERA3 INFO
       Apple Apple Apple Orange  Apple
```

How could I get only the 4th columns data filtered into a single `.xlsx` file and have the next folders csv's put in a new sheet or separate it from the previous folders csv's?

```
concentrated.xlsx | FOLDERA1 FOLDERA2 FOLDERA3   FOLDERB1 FOLDERB2 FOLDERB3
                    ORANGE   CRACKER   ORANGE    ORANGE   CRACKER  ORANGE
```

Comment: Will the script need to traverse multiple folders? You only mention FolderA.

Comment: yes sorry, I wasn't that clear. It needs to go like FolderA 1,2,3.csv FolderB 1,2,3.csv and be able to put that into a single file. The for loop I made could only do the csv's in a single folder

Comment: Is there only 3 csv files per folder? You seem to only mention 3 per folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `usecols` parameter that `pandas.read_csv` comes with.

```
def read_4th(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=1, usecols=[3])

files = ['./1.csv', './2.csv', './3.csv']

big_df = pd.concat([read_4th(fn) for fn in files], axis=1)

big_df.to_excel('./mybigdf.xlsx')
```

For multiple folders use `glob`.

Suppose you have a 2 folders 'FolderA' and 'FolderB' both located in folder './' and you want all csv files in both.

```
from glob import glob

files = glob('./*/*.csv')
```

then run the rest as specified above.

Comment: thank you, your code works well for one folder. But how could I make it loop through the other folders and add it to the same xlsx? Maybe creating a new sheet for each file or append?

Comment: you need a way to get the file names into a list.  you can use the `glob` library to do so.  I'll throw in an example in the answer.

Comment: Very nice solution, I try something similar, but forget for separator and I cannot find problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have suggested using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) as an option, and that will certainly work, but if you are looking for a solution using purely the Python library, you might try using the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module and iterators.

The caveat here is that, depending on the number of files you need to concatenate, you might run into memory constraints. But setting that aside, here is one approach.

### Basic Python Library

```
import csv
from glob import glob
from itertools import izip_longest, imap

# Use glob to recursively get all CSV files. Adjust the pattern according to your need
input_files = (open(file_path, 'rb') for file_path in glob('*.csv'))

# Using generators, we can wrap all the CSV files in reader instances
input_readers = (csv.reader(input_file) for input_file in input_files)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_writer = csv.writer(output_file)

    # izip_longest will return a tuple of the next value 
    # for all the iterables passed as parameters
    # In this case, this means the next row for all the input_readers
    for rows in izip_longest(*input_readers):

        # We extract the fourth column in all the rows
        # Note that this presumes that all files have a fourth column.
        # Some error checking/handling might be required if 
        # you are not sure that's the case 
        fourth_columns = imap(lambda row: row[3], rows)

        # Write to the output the row that is all the 
        # fourth columns for all the readers
        output_writer.writerow(fourth_columns)

# Clean up the opened files
map(lambda f: f.close(), input_files)
```

By using generators, you are minimizing the amount of data to be loaded in memory at once, while maintaining a very Pythonic approach to the problem.

Using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module can make it easier to load multiple files with a known pattern, which seems to be your case. Feel free to replace it with some other form of file lookup, such as [os.path.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk), if it's a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

input_file_paths = ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']

dfs = (pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in input_file_paths)

master_df = pd.concat(
    (df[[c for c in df.columns if c.lower().startswith('folder')]]
        for df in dfs), axis=1)

master_df.to_excel('smth.xlsx')
```

The `df[[c for c in df.columns if c.lower().startswith('folder')]]` line is due to the fact that your example has inconsistent formatting of the folder column.